# For rooted android how to see application databases in File Explorer of Eclipse DDMS tool?

Tags: android, eclipse, file, explorer, ddms

I have root privileges and can access internal databases of android mobile with adb command line tool.

Is it possible to see this in "File Explorer" DDMS view in Eclipse as well , just like we can see all databases for emulator ?

Comment: I have to ask, did you just try doing it via DDMS to see if it works?

Comment: I tried with just DDMS separately. File Explorer do not show anything in it as well. So when its possible through adb shell to list and access /data directory, how DDMS cannot show the same ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem any reason/answer for this.